# Linq Left Join VB.NET To Anonymous Typed List

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-objects, anonymous-types

I am trying to use Linq to accomplish a LEFT OUTER JOIN on list of Anonymous Typed objects where data is Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem 
I would like to display all apps.  Any apps that **have** a support record associated with them, I will display those properties.  Any apps that **do not have** an associated support record, I will display those fields empty.

**Update -** The code below works for the first app returned, which has associated support, but throws the error on the next app in the list which does not have the associated support.  I am stumped as to why I am encountering the null reference error during the `.MoveNext()` on the enumeration.  Any help would be much appreciated.

LINQ + DataBinding

```
Dim q =
  From a In apps.AsEnumerable()
  Group Join s In support.AsEnumerable()
  On a("Title").ToString() Equals CType(s("Product"), FieldLookupValue).LookupValue Into Group
  From ajs In Group.DefaultIfEmpty()
  Select New With {
    .Name = a("Title"),
    .SupportEnd = IIf(ajs Is Nothing, "Unsupported", ajs("End"))
  }

gvApps.DataSource = q.AsQueryable()
gvApps.DataBind()
```

Display

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvApps" runat="server" CssClass="GvApps"
         AutoGenerateColumns="false" EnableViewState="true"
         GridLines="None" CellSpacing="-1">
      <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Application">
          <ItemTemplate>
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name")%>
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Support End">
          <ItemTemplate>
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SupportEnd")%>
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Error**

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. `Select New With {`

**Stack Trace**

- SPDataAccess._Lambda$__5(VB$AnonymousType_0`2 $VB$It1, ListItem appWithSupport)
- System.Linq.d__31`3.MoveNext()
- System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding)

Comment: SharePoint lists aren't tables and shouldn't be treated this way. Worse, the `AsEnumerable()` calls forcefully load *all ListItems* in memory, but not all of their data. For example, the `Product` lookup is probably not loaded.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am fully aware of both your points.  I have no access to change how the SharePoint lists data are arranged or stored, but I have to get data from them.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the product lookup located in the Support list is already loaded along with the apps list.  I only brought back the 4 fields from each of those SharePoint lists that i need.  You can do that using this library.

Comment: The point is - you aren't doing a JOIN between two lists, you are loading everything in memory then trying to do a LINQ to Objects join. Just *don't* call `AsEnumerable()`. The best option though would be to try writing a CAML query that actually does a join and returns what you want. LINQ to SP is an abstraction over CAML. If you can't do this, you can't write a LINQ query either.

Comment: Besides, a NullReferenceException should be very easy to debug - just attach the debugger and see where the exception is thrown. Since you are *not* using LINQ to SP, you can create temporary variables or even use `let` statements in LINQ to store temporary objects for inspection.

Comment: Finally, no LINQ dialect can work with the `SELECT` statement you posted. It's full of client-side processing statements like `Iif`, `Parse`, that have no equivalent to any query language (CAML, SQL etc). Extract the data first, eg to an array and *then* apply client-side transformations.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Your 3rd comment, i completely agree and i know i need to find a better way to filter and not format the data in the LINQ statement.  That will happen next.  The second comment, when i took the entire statement down to its most basic and had it in the debugger, it throws that error on the entire Linq statement, but doesn't specify what line, where or anything.  I am using VS.  Is there a better debugger for this situation.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Finally, if i don't call `AsEnumerable()` it will throw an error on the query because I am using anonymous types.  I can't access or change the SharePoint.ListItem class to be queryable, so that is why i thought to go this route.  I am performing a CAML query before the LINQ to get only certain applications.  My CAML knowledge is completely minimal.  I have tried using a few of the tools to help, but they can only seem to perform extremely basic queries.  The second i attempt a join in CAML, it crashes 2 of the tools. Also, updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            Dim AppsList =
            From a In applications.AsEnumerable()
            Group Join s In support.AsEnumerable()
            On Integer.Parse(a("ID")) Equals CType(s("Product"), FieldLookupValue).LookupId Into Group
            From appSupport In Group.DefaultIfEmpty()
            Order By a("Title") Ascending
            Select New With {
                .AppID = a("ID"),
                .AppViewUrl = AppSettings("ViewURL") & "&ListId={" & AppSettings("AppListGuid") & "}&ID=" & a("ID"),
                .AppName = a("Title"),
                .AppContact = ParseMultivaluedUser(a("App_x0020_Contact"), "No Contacts Listed"),
                .SupportEnd = If(appSupport IsNot Nothing AndAlso Date.TryParse(appSupport.Item("End"), New Date), Date.Parse(appSupport.Item("End")).ToShortDateString, Nothing),
                .Licenses = If(appSupport Is Nothing, Nothing, appSupport.Item("Quantity")),
                .StatusIcon = If(appSupport IsNot Nothing, GetStatusIcon(appSupport.Item("End")), "<span class=""StatusIco Tip NoSupport"" title=""No Support Record""> </span>"),
                .SupportTitle = If(appSupport Is Nothing, Nothing, appSupport("Title")),
                .AkaNames = a("AKA_x0020_Names"),
                .AkaOmit = a("AKA_x0020_Omit"),
                .Installs = GetInstalls(a("ID"), a("AKA_x0020_Names"), a("AKA_x0020_Omit"))
            }
```